# Google analytics - track which pages on external sites are embedding my page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I made a small web page.  Now people are going to embed my small web page on their websites.

I'm trying to figure out how to get google analytics to record which websites are embedding my site.

I'm looking at the API for Event Tracking, but that will require me to write some additional javascript code to detect if there's a parent iframe, then grab the url, and then send to ganalytics.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is using Advance "Custom filters":

```
Field A -> Extract A
Hostname (.*)

Field B -> Extract B
Request URI (.*)

Output To -> Constructor
$A1$B1
```

sample output, Real Time > Content

http://s25.postimg.org/gyg2uci7z/customfilter.png

detailed instruction http://viget.com/advance/getting-more-out-of-google-analytics-advanced-custom-filters

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the website embedding your website in an iframe will show up as the referrer in Google Analytics. Check the "Traffic Sources » Sources » Referral" report in Google Analytics to find out which site embed your website.

In this report, you will of course also see normal referring sites that actually link to your website. You could employ a small script to determine if your website is currently embedded and supply that information to Google Analytics, e.g. as a custom variable:

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 5, "Iframed", (window.self !== window.top) ? "Yes": "No", 2]);
```

Comment: The problem though is that you can't tell the difference between sites iframing you and sites that are actual referring traffic to you (ie. someone clicked a link on that site that went to your site).